# Haskell: Need Help Designing this Function

Tags: haskell

I am trying to design a function that when given a string the function inserts a's and b's into the string.

For example:

Given the string `"Hello"`

The function would return `"aHbealblaob"`.

Comment: Asking for code is off-topic. What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: What are the rules for the insertions?

Comment: @Josh I guess starting with 'a' then alternate between 'b' and 'a'. And finish with a or b.

Comment: I see what you see, @Zacharie007, but the asker needs to be explicit; guesses don't really help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

go figure

```
Prelude> 'a' : (concat $ zipWith (\x y -> x:[y]) "Hello" $ cycle "ba")
"aHbealblaob"
```

or without any details this would do too.

```
f :: String -> String
f "Hello" = "aHbealblaob"
f _       = "not specified"
```

Actually, there is a nice mutual recursive solution similar to odd/even.

```
wrap [] = []
wrap (x:xs) = 'a':x:'b':skip xs
skip [] = []
skip (x:xs) = x: wrap xs

wrap "Hello"
"aHbealblaob"
```